# In GCP Compute Engine Instances API, how does SetMetadata work to notify the VM instance to run a newly added startup script?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm using the Google.Cloud.Compute.V1 client [library](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Compute.V1/) to write a function in a service that creates a VM instance in GCP Compute Engine. Afterwards the function does a few more computations before it makes a call to SetMetadataAsync to add a startup script under the windows-startup-script-ps1 key. My code roughly looks like the below:

```
// There's code above here that creates an Instance object
await machineClient.InsertAsync(ProjectId, Zone, instance, cancellationToken);
// Some other code that doesn't call GCP Compute Engine
instance = await machineClient.GetAsync(ProjectId, Zone, instance.Name, cancellationToken);
var metadata = new Metadata
{
    Fingerprint = instance.Metadata.Fingerprint,
    Items = 
    {
        new Items
        {
            Key = "windows-startup-script-ps1",
            Value = string.Join('\n', script) //script is a list of strings
        }
    }
};

await machineClient.SetMetadataAsync(PProjectId, Zone, instance.Name, metadata, cancellationToken);
```

My code works and the startup script is executed and installs the needed software. So how does GCP Compute Engine work to allow this script to be immediately be executed after being inserted? Or more specifically, where in the Instance lifecycle does a startup script get executed? What are the mechanics behind running a startup script for a machine that has been just created.